# Python Urlib - Ignore Unicode Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I am building a web crawler and I encountered a snag. Basically, the crawler finds all the values for < a href="..." > and then tries to systematically navigate to all of those relative links. For instance, if on the homepage of http://example.com there was the links "home.html" and "about.html" the crawler would move through and try to request the base domain + the newly found domain (ex. http://example.com/home.html, http://example.com/about.html).

However, on my test site I have it setup where there is a < a href="file.pdf" >. When the urlib function in python tries to request the .pdf file I get this error:

[image]

Is there a way that I can build a try / except that ignores the URL if this happens? Here is the current relevant code that I have:

```
def soupify(url):
"""
:param: URL string.
:return: HTML BeautifulSoup object as html.parser
Process: Requests website for HTML code. If it responds, converts the code into IO stream so that it can become a
Soup object.
"""
# Header info so that the web server does not deny the request
hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

# This is to create in memory the HTML code of the page.
file = io.TextIOWrapper(page, encoding='utf-8')
fileContents = file.read()

soupObject = soup(fileContents, "html.parser")
return soupObject
```

Then here is what happens when I try to actually access the URL after it has been soupified.

```
url = baseDomain + queue[0]
queueLength = len(queue)
print("Queue:", queueLength)

isError = False

# Exception handling when attempting to make a soup object.
try: fileContents = soupify(url)
except urllib.error.HTTPError:  # If the website returns an HTTP error, such as a 404
    inaccessibleSites += 1
    isError = True
    queue.pop(0)
except urllib.error.URLError:  # If the website does not exist or does not have a valid URL
    inaccessibleSites += 1
    isError = True
    queue.pop(0)
# Here is where I want to build an except to handle the bad codec but I am not sure where to start
```

The code keeps going but that's the major part that is hitting the error. Any ideas? I imagine it's an easy fix.

Comment: Please post your traceback as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle that `UnicodeDecodeError`, you do the exact same thing you already did to handle `urllib.error.HTTPError` and `urllib.error.URLError`.

So:

```
try:
    fileContents = soupify(url)
except urllib.error.HTTPError:  # If the website returns an HTTP error, such as a 404
    inaccessibleSites += 1
    isError = True
    queue.pop(0)
except urllib.error.URLError:  # If the website does not exist or does not have a valid URL
    inaccessibleSites += 1
    isError = True
    queue.pop(0)
except UnicodeDecodeError:  # If the website is not in UTF-8
    inaccessibleSites += 1
    isError = True
    queue.pop(0)
```

---

Or, since you're not actually doing anything different for the three errors, you could use one `except`:

```
try:
    fileContents = soupify(url)
except (urllib.error.HTTPError, # If the website returns an HTTP error, 
        urllib.error.URLError,  # If the website does not exist or does not have a valid URL
        UnicodeDecodeError):  # If the website is not in UTF-8
    inaccessibleSites += 1
    isError = True
    queue.pop(0)
```

---

But meanwhile, what you probably *really* want to do here is stop assuming every web page is in UTF-8 and instead use the headers and/or meta tags that tell you what the encoding actually is.

Doing this correctly is [not trivial](https://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding). and you might be happier using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) instead of `urllib`, because it has all the logic builtin (except the final "heuristic" step—but `BeautifulSoup` does that part).

If you can't use anything outside the stdlib for some reason:

- The first step is easy: `page.headers.get_content_charset()`.
- The last step is *also* easy: if you can't figure out the encoding, just pass `BeautifulSoup` the bytes and it will use the "Unicode, damnit" heuristics.
- Parsing `META` tags, on the other hand, can be painful. You need to either soupify the binary data and cross your fingers, or decode to ASCII with a non-strict error handling and soupify that, then do `soup.find_all('meta')`, and check each one to see if it has either an `http-equiv="Content-Type"` attribute with a `charset` value, or a `charset` attribute, then you can use that to re-decode and re-soupify.

Comment: Yep that did it! Easy, thanks! And thanks for the advice on how to approach a new way to request, I will look more into it as it might scale it a little better!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add a `except UnicodeDecodeError:` at the bottom of your script and you're good to go.